# How to install android studio on windows without internet?

Tags: android, maven, repository, offline

I want to install on a windows pc Android Studio without internet. I will download all the package before and then install it.
I tried it during 1 week but i don't know how to do.

I don't know how can i download all the "extras" in the SDK with a 26+ version, because since SDK 26, all the files are downloaded directly from the google's maven repository (maven.google.com).
I've tried to retrieve on a local maven repo all the files in the google's repository but it doesn't work at all.

I know that this question has been asked many times but it was 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally, I've got it.

I did this:
- I erased all repositories in the build.gradle

```
repositories {
    *google()*  <-- x
    *jcenter()* <-- x
}
```

- I resolved all the dependencies by adding one by one every files from my "online" pc, .gradle and .m2 (using maven, and adding dependencies to the pom.xml) repositories to the m2repository directory of the "offline" pc.

Answer (score 0):

The
 https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.0.1.0/android-studio-ide-171.4443003-windows.zip 
Doesnt have a installer. Maybe the sdk is already in that file. You can try that

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm downloading it.

Comment: I didn't find any SDK in this file...
I've also tried to copy/paste the .m2 directory (repo) from my own pc to the offline pc but it didn't work too.

Comment: @RastaPopuloS If you are in the windows explorer. go to the program files folder and then go to: Android/Android Studio. If you type sdklib (a folder) in the search box you will find the sdk folder with 26.0.0

Comment: You can also if it is possible, Remove the drive from the ofline pc and install android studio fully on that drive with all the files using the "online pc" .

Comment: I did this but Android Studio was keeping try to download all the files that he needed...